# NLog AspNetSession Layout Renderer - Getting value from strongly typed object in session

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

We are using .NET Core and have extended ISession to allow us to store strongly typed objects as a single item in Session. The code to do that is simple (just so you have an idea):

```
public static void SetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
{
 session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
}
```

Now I'd love to use NLog's AspNetSession layout renderer to try to get the value of one of the properties on the strongly typed object that is in session.

In the NLog config file, I've tried to access a property like this:

```
${aspnet-session:Variable=UserSessionValidationInfo.MstrUserID:EvaluateAsNestedProperties=true}
```

Where "UserSessionValidationInfo" is the key name for the object we stuck in Session and MstrUserID is the property name.

Nothing is returned.

I assume this won't be possible, but I was hopeful, based on the example that was provided here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetSession-layout-renderer

Anyway, does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Would I need to write a custom layout renderer?

Comment: The layout renderer needs to deserialize the json, isn't?

Comment: I actually wrote a Custom Layout Renderer to do the job... The trickiest part was doing DI into the custom layout renderer class. I was able to set it up to inject IHttpContextAccessor into the layout renderer and that gave me assess to HttpContext.

Comment: Yes, DI is tricky as logging is most of the time configured before the DI. We could use some input/experience for this, see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3362